# web api not called from other server of asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web api of mvc 4 in my application.

When I am calling that web api from my computer It is getting data

```
$.getJSON("api/MyAction/?dt=" + dateString,
                function (data) {});
```

but when I deployed project on server It is not working.

Comment: What is server response?(What is error message)

Comment: It is not even giving response. I think url is not getting formed correctly.

Comment: U can use Fiddler for catch respons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for it.

I just added server path before url

i.e.

```
$.getJSON(GetSiteRoot() + "api/MyAction/?dt=" + dateString,
                function (data) {});
```

& my method is

```
function GetSiteRoot() {
    var rootPath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";

    var path = window.location.pathname;

    if (path.indexOf("/") == 0) {

        path = path.substring(1);
    }
    path = path.split("/", 1);

    if (path != "") {
        rootPath = rootPath + path + "/";

    }

    return rootPath;
}
```